# How to make stripe colors for WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

The question is simple: how do I achieve stripe colors for WPF data grids like this:

[image: stripe colors]

This modifies each row to contain gray background, now I need to improve this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#aaa" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the AlternatingRowBackground property of the DataGrid for that.

Answer (score 9):

Use AlternatingRowBackground property of the DataGrid to have the code automatically stripe the rows for you. The Brush color you select will be the alternating color. You can further customize this with AlternationCount property to set how often you want the rows to be alternated (the default is 2 which is most likely what you are looking for based on that picture, but you can always select 3 or more if you want to go hog wild).

```
 <DataGrid AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" AlternationCount="2" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use alternate row color property [AlternatingRowBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.alternatingrowbackground%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to have different color for alternating rows